# open intervals intersection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Here I'm seeking a reference of any sort about this question.
It is known that two open intervals $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$, intersect if and only if $$a_1 < b_2$$ and $$b_1<a_2.$$
Now, I have 4 open intervals $I_1=(a_1,b_1)$,$I_2=(a_2,b_2)$,$I_3=(a_3,b_3)$, and $I_4=(a_4,b_4)$, where $a_i>0$, $b_i>0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. Suppose that these intervals intersect, is there any necessary and sufficient conditions similar to the case above? are there any references talking about such topics? any idea is appreciated!!

Comment: Nitpick: In fact, the condition that those intervals intersect is not correct. The actual condition is $\lnot(b_1\le a_2 \lor b_2\le a_1)$, which is the same as $a_2<b_1\land a_1<b_2$. Also, do you want a condition that they *all* intersect or that *at least two* of them intersect?

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks for commenting. I want all four intervals intersect.

Comment: Wouldn't $\max(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)<\min(b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4)$ do the job? Or, $\bigwedge_{1\le i,j\le 4} (a_i<b_j)$.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: Why does it not? If the intervals intersect, i.e. there is $x\in(a_i, b_i)$ for all $i$, this means that $a_i<x<b_i$ so $\max\{a_i\}<x<\min\{b_i\}$. The other way: if $\max\{a_i\}<\min\{b_i\}$,pick $x$ "between" them (i.e. $\max\{a_i\}<x<\min\{b_i\}$) and then $x\in(a_i,b_i)$ for all $i$ and so the intervals will all intersect. The second condition is just the reformulation of the first. (It is an "and" of $16$ conditions. You can drop four of them if you want, because it is already given that $a_i<b_i$ for all $i$.)

Comment: you're definitely correct. However, in the case where $max\{a_i\}$ can not be determined, this argument would be useless. I'm not working with a numerical example here. Also, it is not possible to determine the max from knowing that all intervals intersect. My bad I should've mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Then you need to improve your question by trying to explain the additional constraints that you have. As I said, the $\max$ formulation can be just converted to $a_1<b_2\land a_1<b_3\land a_1<b_4\land a_2<b_1\land a_2<b_3\land a_2<b_4\land a_3<b_1\land a_3<b_2\land a_3<b_4\land a_4<b_1\land a_4<b_2\land a_4<b_3$. Is this still unworkable for you?

Comment: Yes, this is obvious. I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: This is a different problem: "Can this condition be simplified?". It would be extremely easy to find an example where exactly one of the $12$ conditions would be false so you really need all $12$ of them. Say, you want to falsify only $a_1<b_2$: set $a_2=a_3=a_4=1$, $b_2=2$, $a_1=3$, $b_1=b_3=b_4=4$ i.e. use the intervals $(3,4), (1,2), (1,4), (1,4)$.